# How to register event handlers in the (reverse?) observer pattern?

Tags: python, observer-pattern

I am trying to create a piece of user interface consisting of a grid of draggable pads that can be dropped on each other.

When a pad is dropped on another one, they should swap places.

I want objects of `Pad` and `Pads` classes to be oblivious of each other as much as possible so I thought of applying the observer pattern with those two classes, inheriting from the `Observer` and `Observable` class respectively.

I came up with this boilerplate code:

```
class Observable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.observers = []

    def subscribe(self, observer):
        self.observers.append(observer)

    def unsubscribe(self, observer):
        self.observers.remove(observer)

    def notify(self, data):
        for observer in self.observers:
            observer.receive(data)

class Observer:
    def receive(self, data):
        print('{} received {}'.format(self.id, data))

class Pads(Observable):
    def __init__(self, n_pads):
        super().__init__()
        self.pads = []
        for i in range(1, n_pads + 1):
            pad = Pad(i)
            self.pads.append(pad)
            self.subscribe(pad)

    def swap(self, src_pad, target_pad):
        a = self.pads.index(src_pad)
        b = self.pads.index(target_pad)
        self.pads[a], self.pads[b] = self.pads[b], self.pads[a]
        print('Swapped pad {} with pad {}'.format(src_pad.id, target_pad.id))  

class Pad(Observer):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def drop_on(self, target_pad):
        print('Dropped pad {} on pad {}'.format(self.id, target_pad.id))
        # how to call 'swap' of 'Pads'class automatically here?

pads = Pads(16)
some_pad = pads.pads[8]
another_pad = pads.pads[11]

some_pad.drop_on(another_pad) 

# I do not want to call this manually. Instead, I want it to happen
# automatically after "some_pad.drop_on(another_pad)"
pads.swap(some_pad, another_pad)
```

however, I don't know how to move on from there.

I guess what I need to do is to implement the `notify` method of `Observable` class in such a way that the `swap` method of `Pads` class is automatically called whenever `drop_on` method of `Pad` is called.

Can someone guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm afraid you have multiple issues/design improvements with your code: e.g. `range`, save pads in a dict and not in a list, etc. But the main thing is the OO design: let the Pads (Board would be a better name) object handle the drop event, the swapping and the notification to each pad in case they need to update their id

Comment: I would enable each pad to know its position, decoupling it from its id (please call it `id_` or `name`). And use the position to index the list of the board